# Building kernel 3.7 : use TICK_CPU_ACCOUNTING or IRQ_TIME_ACCOUNTING for AMD 64 Notebook?

Tags: linux, laptop, kernel

I am using make oldconfig and don't know that to do now. (Usually I can make a choice by myself)

```
*
* CPU/Task time and stats accounting
*
Cputime accounting
> 1. Simple tick based cputime accounting (TICK_CPU_ACCOUNTING) (NEW)
  2. Fine granularity task level IRQ time accounting (IRQ_TIME_ACCOUNTING)
choice[1-2]:
```

Seems like IRQ_TIME_ACCOUNTING might have a negative influence performance but was the default before. What to chose?

I am using the notebook mostly for java development debian, firefox, eclipse or intellij.

Comment: After a little more google search I found the answer, better said the kernel help, in form of a patch. As usual it is helpful:

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/546141/

    + bool "Fine granularity task level IRQ time accounting"
    + default n
    + ---help---
    +   Select this option to enable fine granularity task irq time
    +   accounting. This is done by reading a timestamp on each
    +   transitions between softirq and hardirq state, so there can be a
    +   small performance impact.
    +
    +   If in doubt, say N here.

Comment: You may want to expand your final solution into an answer below to help people searching for similar issues in the future.

Comment: Yeah, but my reputation doesn't allow me to answer for another 7 hours :-) Will do after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more google search I found the answer, better said the kernel help, in form of a patch. As usual it is helpful:

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/546141/

```
+   bool "Fine granularity task level IRQ time accounting"
+   default n
+   ---help---
+     Select this option to enable fine granularity task irq time
+     accounting. This is done by reading a timestamp on each
+     transitions between softirq and hardirq state, so there can be a
+     small performance impact.
+
+     If in doubt, say N here.
```